# How to make a contour plot without a square mesh?

Tags: tikz-pgf

My end goal is to plot a color-filled contour plot of my data. The closest I have been is to generate a `surf` with `shader = interp` (which is not exactly what I wanted, but is actually good enough). My figure so far looks like:

[image: Contour]

The problem is that I had to fill all the region I dont want to plot with zeros. This also causes the problem that it creates a fake yellow halo around the edge because it interpolates between the actual value I have and the 0 I had to put next to it.

The data I am using is [complete data](https://pastebin.com/65BF4kQX).

My code so far is:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=2.54cm, bottom=2.54cm, left=2.75cm, right=2.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document} 
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
        [
        width=0.335\paperwidth,
        xlabel = Volts,
        ylabel = Time,
        view={0}{90},
        only marks,
        colorbar,
        colorbar style ={width = 6}
        ]
        \addplot3 [surf,shader=interp] table[x index =0,y index=1,z index=2]{Ekicks.txt};
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The original data I want to plot, without all those zeros I dont need is [clean data](https://pastebin.com/kqTqTRRy).

**EDIT**

Just to be clear, the problem is not that I had to fill the empty space with zeros, I am OK with that. The actual problem is the yellow halo that is generated around the edge, which is due to my zeros instead of the actual data.

**EDIT 2**

So I have been able to make some progress, and I have found a way to generate a filled contour plot using pgfplots. My new result looks like this, which is almost exactly what I want:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
        [
        width=0.335\paperwidth,
        xlabel = Volts,
        ylabel = Time,
        view={0}{90},
        only marks,
        colorbar,
        colorbar style ={width = 6}
        ]
        \addplot3[contour filled={number=40}]
        table[x index =0,y index=1,z index=2]{Ekicks.txt};
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

My problem is that I still need to have a complete mesh. Does anybody know how I could just plot the values I need? Or how can I work around this, something like force all 0 to white, while all the other colors remain the same?

Comment: I think you might be looking for a filled contour plot (which requires gnuplot).

Comment: Thanks, I will be looking at gnuplot today. Do you know if I can ignore points, as I want, with gnuplot? And just for curiosity, is it possible to get something similar with a shader plot as above? Something like force the 0 into white, while everyother color remains the same?

Comment: How about the result of `\addplot3 [contour filled={number=14, }] table[x index =0,y index=1,z index=2]{Ekicks.txt};`? (My main problem is that when I run your code on my machine, the contour looks different. It is almost vertical.)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat isn't that the same I have on my second edit? W.r.t. your problem, it is because I have removed a lot of data so that it all fits in the question. I will add the complete data (with and without the unnecessary zeros) in a bit.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I have now added all the data (both with and without zeros) in a pastebin link. It should now be possible to replicate the exact figures in my question. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! Just to be clear: the statement "Just to be clear, the problem is not that I had to fill the empty space with zeros, I am OK with that. " under the first edit is obsolete now, right? You want to feed pgfplots with data that is not in matrix form but still want to get the result that is shown at the very bottom of the question?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Well, the actual problem is still the unreal interpolation caused by the zeros (even in the image of the very bottom). So to avoid an XY problem, I wouldn't call the edit obsolete; maybe the solution comes from manipulating the domain in which the function is colored rather than where it is plotted, I don't know. So I think that the question, as it is, would make an answer (and the question) more helpful to people from the future.

Answer (score 1):

When you indicate your absent data with `nan` instead of `0` you can ask `pgfplot` to `jump` over these data points instead of `discard`ing them using the `unbounded coords` key. This gives you a better visual representation of your actual data. With the downside that you do not have an extrapolation into the undetermined area, resulting in a ragged boundary.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  width=.7\linewidth,
  xlabel={Potential in Volt},
  ylabel={Time},
  view={0}{90},
  colorbar,
  unbounded coords=jump
] \addplot3 [
  surf,
  shader=interp,
] table [
  x index=0,
  y index=1,
  z index=2,
]{plot.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The resulting plot look like this:

[image: image of the plot result]

Comment: I have awarded the bounty, as it seems to solve exactly what I wanted. I will check later when I have time. My problem with NaN was that it joined the last element on each row with the first one of the next one. It seems that the 'unbound cord = jump' solves this right?

Comment: With the default setting of `unbounded coords=discard` `pgfplots` tries to interpolate values for the `nan` entries. In the two dimensional projections this leads to unacceptable zigzag artifacts. With `jump` these values are simply ignored.

Comment: I have not really looked into the problem, but just in case you want to `jump` on zero: `z filter/.expression={z==0? nan : z}, unbound cord=jump`